# Multiline Balloon Hints in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I am changing my applications tooltips to use BalloonHints. For the test I am using a single line and it is displayed nicely. But when the hint text is multi-line (i.e existing hints look like this ...

```
'This is a test' + #13 + 'Hello'+ #13 + 'Hello'+ #13 + 'Hello'+ #13 + 'Hello'
```

When this is displayed in the BalloonHint, the size is wrong and the whole list of entries are offset so that they disappear.

Anyone got any helpful suggestions ?

Update: It seems it is the title that messes the display up. I'll report it in qc.

Comment: Linebreak in win is #13#10, you only use #13... does changing to #13#10 make any difference?

Comment: @ain: I tried that, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Delphi 2009. I'll try again with xe2

Answer (score 6):

So you already knew that if you put #13#10 into the properties inspector that's actually only putting the characters literally into the string. Do it this way instead:

```
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Button1.Hint := 'This is a test' + #13 + 'Hello'+ #13 + 'Hello'+ #13 + 'Hello'+ #13 + 'Hello';

end;
```

When I try it in Delphi XE, it looks fine to me.
[image]

TMS's [hint component](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/htmlhint.asp) is much nicer -- so if you can switch to something else, try that.  You could also try TJvBalloonHint in JVCL.

Comment: P: You are right. When I tried it, I used also a title on the hint, and then it doesn't work with a multi-line text. I assumed that this was the OP's problem, but now I am not sure any more. Try, for example, `Button1.Hint := 'This is a test|'#13'Hello'#13'Hello'#13'Hello'#13'Hello';`

Comment: This is extremely odd. When I start a comment with `@Warren P`, the part `@Warren` is automatically removed...

Comment: I don't trust TBalloonHint either, but I can't reproduce its problems just now in XE, it seems fine. If it wraps a common control then the bugs are probably MSCommon Controls version bugs.

Comment: So titles on hints are incompatible with multiline text?  Definitely a good reason to ditch this and go to a different hint component.

Comment: However the hint rect was calculated it doesn't adjust for titles, on multilines.  If that is inside the delphi code, it should be put in QC.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1055/discussion-between-warren-p-and-andreas-rejbrand)

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand See [what happened to my @ salutation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation).